# Eclipse @Singleton Created Twice

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have a persistent bean,

```
@Creatable
@Singleton
public class PersistentBean extends PersistentType {

  private final Helper helper;
  private final IEventBroker eventBroker;

  @Inject
  public PersistentBean(Helper helper, IEventBroker eventBroker) {
    this.helper = helper;
    this.eventBroker = eventBroker;
  }

  @PostConstruct
  private void postConstruct() {
    setTaxYear(TaxYear.TY2013.toString());
  }

  // stuff ...
}
```

With Eclipse tracing activated, this ctor and postConstruct() are called TWICE.  Odd given that this class is a @Singleton?

setTaxYear() triggers unmarshalling and asks Helper to compute assorted results.

When Helper calls Provider.get(), it receives null and crashes.  What's up with that?  The already-created singleton bean is calling it.

Thanks in advance for any advice, I read related posts without success,
Dave.

--- Update for Greg

```
public class PersistentBean extends PersistentType {

  public void setTaxYear(String taxYear) {
    unmarshal(taxYear);
  }

  private void unmarshal(String taxYear) {
    // Unmarshal file into jaxBean, works fine.
    PersistentType jaxBean = <elided>;
    // Copy jaxBean into this object's state, no problem.
    // Now update derived data (mucho problema).
    helper.updateTax();
  }
}

public class Helper extends AClass {

  private final Provider<PersistentBean> persistentProvider;
  private PersistentBean persistent;

  @Inject
  public Helper(Provider<PersistentBean> persistentProvider) {
    this.persistentProvider = persistentProvider;
  }

  BigDecimal updateTax() {
    if (persistent == null)
      persistent = persistentProvider.get();
    // Result is null, attempts to use cause NPE.
    // And sometimes (?) goes into infinite loop?
  }
}
```

It is confusing.  All I can think of is that @PostConstruct is still running in context of PersistentBean constructor so the PersistentBean is not officially created when Helper tries to get it?  Maybe E4 doesn't know about a @Singleton until both its constructor and postConstructor return?  Makes it kinda hard to initialize state.

Comment: How is `PersistentBean` being created?  What is `Provider.get()`?

Comment: PersistentBean is created with data injection @Inject everywhere except in Helper which uses Provider<PersistentBean> to avoid circular dependency. javax.inject.Provider<T> has method get() to retrieve PersistentBean as needed in Helper methods.  If Helper tried to retrieve its PersistentBean during construction, result is stack overflow as PersistentBean also injects a Helper.

Comment: Where are you get the instance of the Provider interface from? I'm not clear if this is Eclipse e4 direct injection or one of the other injector frameworks.

Comment: Mars IDE includes javax.inject_1.0.0.v20091030.jar containing Provider interface.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Provider.html.

Looks like Eclipse implements the interface with

org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.ProviderImpl.

Comment: Yes I know that. You haven't shown us the code where you use the provider which makes it very difficult to determine exactly what is happening.

Comment: i updated code sample above.